# ImportError: No module named flask.ext.storage

Tags: python, flask

I am working on [this example](http://flask-uploads.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) of image uploading with Flask-Upload but when I run the code, python says:

> "ImportError: No module named flask.ext.storage"

(I successfully installed Flask, SQLAlchemy, Flask-Upload by using pip)

Here are all packages I have installed on myproject:

[image: installed packages])

I have googled, but I can not find any way to fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
$ pip install -e git://github.com/kvesteri/flask-storage.git#egg=Flask-Storage
```

That project lives here: https://github.com/kvesteri/flask-storage